# SQL statement to find last word in string

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with a text field that contains one or more words, separated by spaces. I want to isolate the last word in that text field. For example if the table contained:

```
|col1 |
+-----+
|a    |
|b c  |
|d e f|
```

I want a query that will return:

```
|result|
+------+
|a     |
|c     |
|f     |
```

Thanks in advance!

Barry

P.S. I am running MySQL 5.1

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(TRIM(col1), ' ', -1) FROM table;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index